# Bulk insertion using Visual Studio 2010 in C#

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a dictionary database in a C# project that contain large amount of words and their meanings. My database has a table named "dic", that have 2 columns: first is "english" (the one which contains the English word) and the second is "bangla" (which contains the meaning).
I have 2 text files: `english.txt` containing 20000 words and `bangla.txt` containing their meanings.
i tried put the query on visual stdio 2010 like :

```
BULK INSERT dic FROM 'C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Desktop\wordddd\good one\list.txt' 
WITH (  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )
```

But it didnt work.shows the error "The BULK INSERT SQL construct or statement is not supported";
How can I insert these words and their meaning into the "dic" table from the two txt files using bulk insertion of MS SQL? can anyone tell me details about this ??

Comment: Use the [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SqlBulkCopy class is just for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i tried to use it but i cant do that.Can you help me how to do that.@Wiktor

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work more precisely? Could you show your code? It's quite difficult to tell you what might be wrong with your code if you are not showing it.